# Select box with empty option, which is not present in html dom

Tags: html, html-select

At this website: http://www.salus.si/en (if you click on "change" in top banner*) the select element starts with an empty option. HTML looks like this:

```
<select id="cc-preference-selector-analytics">
    <option value="yes">I accept</option>
    <option value="no">I do not accept</option>
</select>
```

Here is the same select element in jsfiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/JG89n - which shows the first option. Why is this happening?

Thanks.

**If you have "Send do not track headers" enabled in your browser, you wont see the banner. Its a cookie consent banner which doesn't get displayed if user has this feature enabled. IE10 has it enabled by default. Banner looks like this (top of the page): [image: Site screenshot]*

Comment: sorry, but where is the "change" option in the top banner, i cant find it :P. Maybe there is some script executed to add an empty option?

Comment: If you have "Send do not track headers" enabled in your browser, you wont see the banner. Its a cookie consent banner which doesn't get displayed if user has this feature enabled. IE10 has it enabled by default.

Comment: I probably see what you call “top banner”, but it has no “change” element and the HTML (even the generated HTML) does not contain any `select` element.

Comment: OK now I see **change** in the mass of the tiny text, and clicking on it creates a popup-like dialog. This is usability nightmare, and accessibility nightmare. I suggest that you redesign the whole allow/disallow cookie business or omit it, instead of trying to fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the default option, so it displays empty.

If you want default selection as "I accept", do this way:-

```
<select id="cc-preference-selector-analytics">
    <option value="yes" selected="selected">I accept</option>
    <option value="no">I do not accept</option>
</select>
```

### Update:

Mostly like, this is a browser behaviour and also I think your javascript can also cause this issue.

Comment: FYI: In XHTML/HTML5, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the `selected` attribute must be defined as `<option selected="selected">`. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: Thanks. But here is the jsfiddle with same code http://jsfiddle.net/JG89n/ - which shows the first option. Why is this happening?

Comment: you have to add the selected="selected" attribute as Siva Charan said and Alfie correted :). In addition this could be browser specific, i get the first value also without the seleted attribute in firefox.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that the message seems to be added with javascript (and it probably behaves differently because of that?) rather than being loaded in the html document itself.

Comment: Samurai8, here: http://www.bb-krema.com/intro the same js is used, same html for select box is generated, but result is different - there is no empty option.

Comment: @Alfie, FYI: It does not count for HTML5. Your unofficial source does not even say so. And neither does w3. There is nothing again minimizing in HTML, it's only just not allowed in XML.

Comment: You are right - it is optional for HTML5. I stand corrected :)